# How do I scroll up and down a SideBar rather than the whole window?

Tags: css, reactjs, addeventlistener, onscroll

I will only show relevant code as there is a lot of it. This is the parent component App:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-side" aria-label="Side Navigation">
                <div className={`navbar-toggler ${this.state.notification ? 'has-notification' : ''}`} data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebarCollapse" aria-controls="sidebarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle side navigation">
                    Menu
                </div>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="sidebarCollapse">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li className="nav-user">
                            <div className="profile-pic">
                                <i className="fa fa-lg fa-user mt-1" />
                            </div>
                            <i><span>{this.state.authenticatedUser.first_name} {this.state.authenticatedUser.last_name}</span><br />{this.state.authenticatedUser.job_title}</i>
                        </li>
                        <NavBar />
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
```

This is the Navbar component:

```
class NavBar extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        auth: false,
        slide: 0,  // How much should the Navbar slide up or down
        lastScrollY: 0,  // Keep track of current position in state
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    let navbar = document.getElementById('navbar-div');
    navbar.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    let navbar = document.getElementById('navbar-div');
    navbar.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

handleScroll = () => {
    let navbar = document.getElementById('navbar-div');
    const { lastScrollY } = this.state; 
    const currentScrollY = navbar.scrollY;

    if (currentScrollY > lastScrollY) {
      this.setState({ slide: '-48px' });
    } else {
      this.setState({ slide: '0px' });
    }
    this.setState({ lastScrollY: currentScrollY });
};

render() {
    return (
        <div className="navbar-div" id="navbar-div">
            {this.adminMenu()}
            {this.usersMenu()}
        </div>
    );
}

}
```

adminMenu and usersMenu are just arrays of objects which output the object names. The error I get says navbar is null hence it cannot add an event listener onto a null object. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `componentDidMount` rather than `componentWillMount`. The latter will run before any markup is rendered.

You can read more about lifecycle methods here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class

However, I'd highly recommend you to apply a handler on the element instead of `componentDid/Will/Mount/Unmount`, like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="navbar-div" id="navbar-div" onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
            {this.adminMenu()}
            {this.usersMenu()}
        </div>
    );
}
```